# Get all the post that a Page is Tagged in using FQL Stream table

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to get all the Posts that a Page is tagged in using the stream table in FQL?
Apparently the only indexed column is source_id but i can only use it to get the posts that where created ON the Page. But what with posts that were created on a User timeline but tagged with the Page?

If there is no way of doing it with FQL. Then, there is a way of doing it with the Graph API using the Tagged connection of the Page object. BUT, how can i filter between dates with the graph API? like get all posts from a connection stream where updated_date is between x and y?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

post_id is also an indexed field.  You can use subqueries or joins to get this information from the stream_tag table

`SELECT message FROM stream WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM stream_tag WHERE target_id = me()) AND updated_time > LAST_TIME_YOU_CHECKED`